# Maximum and minimum cardinality of range and preimage

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I found the following question related to understanding of images and preimages:

> Let A and B be nonempty sets and $f$ be a function $f: A \rightarrow  B$. In terms of $|A|$ and $|B|$, what is the maximum possible cardinality of
> $f[A]$? What is the minimum possible cardinality of $f[A]$? How about $f^{-1}[B]$?

My thoughts are the following:

1. The maximum possible cardinality of $f[A]$ is $|B|$, since $f[A]$ is the range of the function and the function might be surjective, so it will map to all the elements of $B$
2. Minimum cardinality of $f[A]$ is $1$, because $f[A]$ might be a function which maps all the elements to a single element of $B$.
3. Maximum and minimum possible cardinality of $f^{-1}[B]$ is $|A|$, because we have a preimage of entire codomain, which must be an entire domain for $f$ to be a well-defined function.

I'm almost sure of my answers, but I'd be very grateful if someone could check and criticise/correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. And I also doubt about the second point - my answer states that cardinality is $1$, but the question asks me to define the cardinalities in terms of $|A|$ and $|B|$. Is this possible to do in the second point?

Comment: To give a definite answer, we need to know a little bit more about $f$. Is $f$ a mapping from $A$ to $B$. Or is it a mapping from $X$ to $Y$ with $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$?

Comment: $f: A \rightarrow B$. Good point actually, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your statements 2 and 3.

For statement 1, there might be a ``trap".

Well, here are two things we know about the maximum cardinality of $f[A]$, say $|f[A]|_{MAX}$.

1. $|f[A]|_{MAX} \le |A|$ by the definition of a function.
2. $|f[A]|_{MAX} \le |B|$ by the fact $f[A]$ is a subset of $B$.

Since we don't know which is larger between $|A|$ and $|B|$, it is better to say $|f[A]|_{MAX} = \min\left\{ |A|, |B|\right\}$

Comment: Great observation about the third case. Thanks!